# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working in generic handler

Tags: asp.net, cors, generic-handler

I want to use cross-domain ajax, thus I had to use either [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), or use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). Due to technical problems I had, I chose to use CORS. Thus, I created a generic handler in the target website (say http://www.target.com/handler.ashx) and I sent ajax requests to that handler from http://www.source.com/.

However, browser didn't show anything and when I saw the HTTP Headers of the response, I didn't see any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header there.

What's wrong?

Comment: As the author of the handler, you yourself are responsible for setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Are you doing this in handler.ashx?

Comment: Yeah @monsur, I do it. But I don't see it in browser.

Comment: What are you using to view headers? You won't see the Access-Control-* headers in Firebug or Chrome's console because these headers are hidden by the browser. If you use a packet analyzer like Wireshark, it will show exactly what headers are exchanged between the browser and the server.